# autohotkey input text into Yahoo search box

Tags: autohotkey

I'm trying to input text into Yahoo search box but for some reason it doesn't work. It works for the Bing and just wanted to know why it doesn't wrk for Yahoo.

**Here is my code**

```
IEGet(name="") {
   IfEqual, Name,, WinGetTitle, Name, ahk_class IEFrame     ;// Get active window if no parameter
   Name := (Name="New Tab - Windows Internet Explorer")? "about:Tabs":RegExReplace(Name, " - (Windows|Microsoft)? ?Internet Explorer$")
   for wb in ComObjCreate("Shell.Application").Windows()
      if wb.LocationName=Name and InStr(wb.FullName, "iexplore.exe")
         return wb
}

wb := IEGet("Yahoo") ;IE instance already open and tab named google exists


wb.document.All.p.value := "tu1"


MsgBox, Done!
```

The website is https://uk.yahoo.com/?p=us and I'm Autohotkey is using an existing tab.

Answer (score 0):

```
; your function above...
oMouseEvents:=(oDoc:=IEGet("Yahoo").document).createEvent("MouseEvents")
oMouseEvents.initEvent("click", True, True)
oDoc.querySelector("#UHSearchBox").value:="tu1"
oDoc.querySelector("#UHSearchWeb").dispatchEvent(oMouseEvents)
```

Comment: Hi Grey - your answer would be more useful if you could add some explanation of how and why this works. It would be helpful, both to the original questioner and to any other reader searching for help with similar problems.

Answer (score -1):

Try without "p"

```
wb.document.All.value := "tu1"
```

Comment: Your answer would be better with a bit more context; perhaps you could show how your analysis of the DOM has led you to this answer?

Comment: I want to suggest , as you can see I am unable to made comment , :( my repo is 16, well as you can see he is trying to set value of all elements to "tu1" but and P is was strange thing i have seen, that is how I made suggestion. If I know what is p then I could define.

Comment: Until you have the reputation to add comments, I think you need to work on posting good, completely, answers or questions which will get upvoted. You shouldn't be posting an "answer" which is really a comment on the question.

Comment: Yah ... I am getting understand this political strategy/policy :)